# IIS running ASP.NET MVC 5 64 bit app AND 32 bit app

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-5, 32bit-64bit

So - you can't run 64 bit and 32 bit in the same process.. I get that. I have a mostly 64 bit app that needs to send data to a 32 bit ODBC driver - that is the only 32 bit part of the app. Up until now I just forced the whole app to 32 bit - but it seems a waste on a decent server.  Any ideas around the best way to send data from a 64 bit app to a 32 bit process? ( .Net 4.6.1 )

Comment: Swap the ODBC driver for a different one?  Wrap it in a web service if that is not possible?

Comment: ok thanks . Maybe a WCF service wrapper?  There is no 64 bit driver.

Comment: Yes I figured as much...  WCF is ok.. If it is going to be internal meaning you're not going to expose it to external client which I don't think you are, you'll want whatever you decide to wrap it in to be as lightweight as possible.  What is the nature of the transactions?  Lots of small transactions or fewer large ones, etc?  If you wrap it you'll want to weigh the cost of doing so against the benefits of going 64 bit.

Comment: There isn't much interconnected data going through processes.  basically the 64 bit process tells the 32 bit process to copy all the data to SQL Server. Once the data is in SQL server the rest of the 64 bit app just uses SQL server.   I am having an issue getting WCF going in 32 bit mode on Local IIS though ( WCF Service application ) .  It simply will not let me!  

I have tried locking everything down to 32 bit ( everything default out of the box without referencing anything ) - it works in 64 bit but not 32 bit gfor some reason